# Should I use empty website or spa web application template for an Angular 2 project in Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, angular, templates, visual-studio-code

For an angular project every tutorial on web, indicates to use Visual Studio Code. I am familiar with visual studio environment for like ten years besides there will be more project in my solution. Visual studio code is fine for an angular project but what about other projects in my solution? like services or class libraries.
So i decided to use visual studio 2017 rather than visual studio code. But i couldnt decide which template to choose for angular project, a website or spa template? And is there a way to run an angular project on nodejs just clicking run button.

Comment: Your questions are vague and tools are a matter of opinion to the developer. You should try out making the application yourself and come back here when you have more pointed questions

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using the Angular CLI if possible. The CLI adds tooling for testing and AOT among other things that will save you a lot of time in the future.

here is an article about using the CLI with Visual Studio in an MVC app it may give you more info on specifics that you have.

http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent custom templates available for Visual Studio. I personally use this one for Visual Studio 2015. However, I am sure it would work for Visual Studio 2017.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Drag13.Angular2WebTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the new templates available via "dotnet new" such as "dotnet new angular" You can find out more here: https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/